# Create a PostgreSQL query with possibility of a Null relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, relationship

Suppose I have the following tables where id in each are primary keys and actors in the second is a foreign key of the first.

```
 table: actors
 id |              name              
----+--------------------------------
  1 | Paul Rudd            
  2 | Danny Devito             
  3 | Mark Ruffalo 
  4 | David Allen Grier      

table: movies
 id |     name      | actors
----+---------------+----------------
  1 | So this is 40 |              1
  2 | Avengers      |              3
  3 | Twins         |              2
```

I need to write a single sql query that will select all movie names with and their actors and actors without movies

This is what I have:

```
SELECT IFNULL(m.name, 'none'), a.name
FROM actors a
JOIN movies m
ON m.id = a.id;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  function ifnull(character varying, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT IFNULL(n.name, 'none'), l.name

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need 
to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql:

```
 SELECT m.name, a.name
 FROM movies m 
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN actors a 
 ON m.actors = a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me, check it out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dd116/3). You are not using the correct single quote `'` in your query.

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(m.name, 'none'), a.name
FROM actors a
JOIN movies m
ON m.id = a.id;
```

Comment: @steve you can check in the demo link I have provided, it is working fine.

Comment: I made a mistake; this is not mysql it is postgresql. I updated the post, sorry.

Comment: @steve updated my answer. you need to use `coalesce()`. look at the demo I have provided.

Comment: thank you, I ended up solving with a right outter join. I've updated the post with the solution.

Comment: @steve you should be very clear on what you need. Your post was completely different then what you just updated now.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this whole time I was working in myself, not postgesql. Other than that, what else changed?

Comment: this is postgresql, not mysql, but I will accept it